# Solve $2^x\equiv 5\pmod{13}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know the solution is $x\equiv  9 \pmod{12}$.
I worked it by doing the donkey work of taking powers of $2$ : $2^2, 2^2, 2^3, \ldots, 2^{12}$ and picking the one that reduces to $5$. Just wondering if there is any other efficient method to solve the congruence when the variable is in exponent ? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think systematic solutions of these are hard to find (this is the discrete logarithm problem). There isn't always a solution - here $2$ is a primitive root.

However there are sometimes short cuts we might notice in specific cases. Little Fermat tells us that $2^{12}\equiv 1 \bmod 13$

If we note that $5\times 8=40\equiv 1\equiv 2^{12r} \bmod 13$ and dividing by $8=2^3$ gives the answer.

Here we also have $5^2=25\equiv -1\bmod 13$. This tells us that $5$ is a quadratic non-residue and the power $x$ is therefore odd (even powers would be quadratic residues). And that can help to reduce possibilities.

Note also that $2^6=64\equiv -1\bmod 13$ is easy to calculate, and that observation reduces the work of computing powers considerably.

Answer (score 3):

$$2^x\equiv5\equiv-8\equiv-2^3\pmod{13}$$

$$\iff2^{x-3}\equiv-1$$

Now $2^{12}\equiv1\pmod{13}\iff13|(2^6+1)(2^6-1)$ and we actually have $2^6\equiv-1\pmod{13}$

Clearly,$6$ is the smallest positive exponent

$\implies x-3\equiv6\pmod{12}$